# How to remove square bracket from Dataframe column using pyspark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have Dataframe df and column name is text as below and I wanted to remove square bracket from this
Input

```
[gh].[ijdnd]
[hyf]
dfvc.gfth
[]
[
 ]
```

Output

```
gh.ijnd
hyf
dfvc.gfth
null
null
null
```

Comment: https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-regexp_replace-replace-string-value/  here's an example of how to do string replacement in a column.

Answer (score 2):

Let us use `regexp_replace` to substitute square brackets with empty string then mask the empty values with null

```
r = F.regexp_replace('text', r'\[|\]', '')
r = F.when(r == '', F.lit(None)).otherwise(r)
result = df.withColumn('text', r)
```

---

```
+---------+
|     text|
+---------+
| gh.ijdnd|
|      hyf|
|dfvc.gfth|
|     NULL|
|     NULL|
|     NULL|
+---------+
```